# Flatten Hierarchy of Dataset

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I need to flatten the hierarchy of a data set using a base table and a parent-child table. The issue with the table structure is that the parent-child table does not include records for parents with no children and children can have multiple parents and parents can have multiple children.

Initially, the approach was to build out a tree

```
with parent_record as(
   select * from main_table where id not in (select child_id from parent_child_table)
),
first_level as ( 
   (select p.id as prev_parent, p.id as parent, nvl(l.child_id,null) as child, 0 as 
   leaf from parent_record p left outer join parent_child_table l on p.id=l.id)
union all
   (select l.parent as prev_parent, m.id as parent, m.child_id as child, (l.leaf + 1) as leaf
   from first_level l inner join parent_child m on l.child = m.id)
),
tree as (
(select
   parent as p1,
   child as c1,
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as p2
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as c2
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as p3
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as c3
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as p4
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as c4
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as p5
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as c5
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as p6
   cast(null as varchar(x)) as c6
   prev_parent,
   child,
   leaf
from first_level where leaf = 0
)
union all 
(select
   tree.p1,
   tree.c1,
   case when (source.leaf = 1) then source.parent else tree.p2 end as p2,
   case when (source.leaf = 1) then source.child else tree.c2 end as c2,
   case when (source.leaf = 2) then source.parent else tree.p3 end as p3,
   case when (source.leaf = 2) then source.child else tree.c3 end as c3,
   case when (source.leaf = 3) then source.parent else tree.p4 end as p4,
   case when (source.leaf = 3) then source.child else tree.c4 end as c4,
   case when (source.leaf = 4) then source.parent else tree.p5 end as p5,
   case when (source.leaf = 4) then source.child else tree.c5 end as c5,
   case when (source.leaf = 5) then source.parent else tree.p6 end as p6,
   case when (source.leaf = 5) then source.child else tree.c6 end as c6,
   source.parent as prev_parent,
   source.child,
   source.Leaf
   from first_level source join tree on tree.child = source.parent and tree.prev_parent = source.prev_parent)
)
```

The next thought process was to use another CTE to just pull the initial parent and then all of the children and take the max leaf. The issue with this is that it removes records where there is a parent with multiple children and those children have different levels of depth.
for example
p-c1a-c2a-c3a
would be returned but p-c1b-c2b would be filtered out due to it having a lower final leaf.

Selecting the parent, each child and the leaf returns all records of relation with every level of leaf

| p1 | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | leaf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | null | null | null | null | null | 0 |
| a | b | null | null | null | null | 1 |
| a | b | c | null | null | null | 2 |
| a | d | null | null | null | null | 1 |

filtering by max leaf would return

| p1 | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | leaf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | null | null | null | 2 |

the target table would look something like this

| p1 | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | leaf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | null | null | null | 2 |
| a | d | null | null | null | null | 1 |

Is the tree still usable and if not what would be a better approach to tackle this?

Comment: I strongly recommend using example data to demonstrate what you're starting with and how you want to represent it in your output.  For example, if A is the parent of B and C, and then B and C are both parents of D (a diamond shape), what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is there any way you can give us a CTE for `main_table`, so we can test queries over it to reply?